# Run time Error in the Program of Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){

int b=90;
int*  a;
a=&b;
//pointer arith metic
printf("Address a is %d\n",a);
printf("size of integer is %d bytes\n",sizeof(int));
printf("Address a is %d\n",*a);
printf("Address a+1 is %d\n",a+1);
printf("value  of a+1 is %d\n",*(a+1));

char *ip;
ip=(char*)&b;
printf("Address ip is %d\n",ip);
}
```

Output of the Program :

```
Address a is 1495857868
size of integer is 4 bytes
Address a is 90
Address a+1 is 1495857872
value  of a+1 is 1495857868
Address ip is 1495857868
Address ip is 90
```

1.there is always 4 byte gap between the address of the a+1 position and and

2.The output for the value at *(a+1) and the address of variable b when the
 pointer converts to char becomes equal
3.Though the pointer value converts into char it shows full value of the variable

```
ip=(char*)&b;
printf("Address ip is %d\n",*ip);
```

the output:Address ip is 90

Comment: `*(a+1)` leads to undefined behavior...

Comment: what's your issue?

Comment: Print a pointer's value itself like this `printf("Address a is %p\n",(void*)a);` as opposed to the value it is pointing to.

Comment: Consider editing your question to better format it

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
a + 1
```

when `a` has type `int *` will print the address incremented by the size of one `int`. This is known as *pointer arithmetic* and is one of C's most core features when it comes to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.there is always 4 byte gap between the address of the a+1 position

Gap bytes is determine by type of pointer: char pointer--> gap bytes are 1 byte, int pointer --> gap bytes are 4 bytes ...

In this case: variable a is int pointer --> Gap bytes are 4 bytes

==>Offset of Address (a+1) and (a) is 4 byte (1495857872 - 1495857868 = 4)

> 2. The output for the value at *(a+1) and the address of variable b when the pointer converts to char becomes equal

Value at address (a+1) is can not predic, it base on your system.

1. I run in my PC, result is:

   Address b is:         2665524

   value  of a+1 is:     2665720
2. If you change your code a little, Add ***(a+1) = 5;*** before: **//pointer arith metic***

Then run --> result become:

```
Address b is:         2665524
value  of a+1 is:     5
```

> 3.Though the pointer value converts into char it shows full value of the variable

It show full value of the variable because value of b is 90, this value only need 1 byte to store in memory, so when convert it to char (1 byte in memory) you saw that value after convert to char equal with int value.

if you asign b > 255, ex: int b=290;

Then run --> result become:

```
Value a is:         290
value ip is:        34
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change :

```
printf("Address a is %d\n",a);
```

to

```
printf("Address a is %p\n",a); //%p is specifically designed for pointers.
```

Till

```
printf("Address a+1 is %d\n",a+1);
```

your code should be fine. But the next statement is problematic

```
printf("value  of a+1 is %d\n",*(a+1));
```

As `a` is a pointer `a+1` will advance `a` by the number of bytes `int` occupies in your system. Then, by doing *(a+1) you're trying to access a memory location which is not assigned for a.(Remember `a` is meant only to store the address of one integer when you do `a=&b;`).

When you're try to de-reference a memory location which you have no right to, the behavior is undefined as per C standards.

> 3.Though the pointer value converts into char it shows full value of the variable

```
ip=(char*)&b;
```

The statement **Though the pointer value converts into char** is wrong.It is just that you're treating the contents in address `&b` as characters. Then you have:

```
printf("Address ip is %d\n",*ip); 
// Remember you're printing the value not address. So change the print message
```

Remember that the any data is stored as bits ie `zeroes` or `ones` and it is the format specifier that you choose which determines how it is displayed. Here you are printing the contents in the `&b` as an integer as you have mentioned in `%d` in `printf` so you get 90 as the result. Fortunately for you the number `90` is small enough to be contained in one byte.

Suppose you changed the printf to :

```
printf("Value pointed to by ip is %c\n",*ip); // %d to %c
```

You should have got

```
Value pointed to by ip is Z
```

Here `90` is interpreted as an ASCII code which corresponds to letter `Z`.

Comment: `printf("Address a+1 is %d\n",a+1); ` when I used %p i get the address as this **Address p is 0x7fff137fdfa4
**
and when I print :`ip=(char*)&b;
printf("Address ip is %d\n",*ip);

the output:valueof ip is 90`.

Comment: When you use `%p` you get the result in hexadecimal format. You can differentiate hex numbers by the prefix `0x`

Comment: how the 3rd parts happen in my question